# DateFormatter producing unexpected result on device

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code:

```
var components = DateComponents()
components.year = 2017
components.month = 1

var calendar = Calendar.current
let date = calendar.date(from: components)!

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("MMMMYYYY")
let string = formatter.string(from: date)
```

When I run this in the simulator on my computer it works as I would expect and the value of `string` is **January 2017**.

However, when I run the same code on my device the value of `string` is **January 2016**. What can be causing this difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference could be

- A different locale on device and simulator.

and / or

- `YYYY` is year in a *Week of Year* based calendar.
- `yyyy` is year in standard calendar.

You should always use `yyyy`.

Comment: Yes, using `yyyy` fixes it. Not sure why I was using `YYYY`. Probably just cap lock happy.